# Performance Penalty for using VMWare Fusion shared folders

Tags: windows-7, vmware-fusion

I have a OSX MacBook Pro running 10.10.2 (Yosemite) and VMWare Fusion 7.

The guest operating system is Windows 7.

I do development (Using Eclipse) on the Windows 7 box and want to put my workspace on a shared folder so that the source is backed up using time machine.

In other words, I will create a folder on the host (Yosemite) and share that folder with the guest (Windows) using the `Virtual Machine->Settings->Sharing` feature in VMWare.

In the context of using Eclipse, will there be a significant performance penalty for configuring the system like this?

What other problems should I anticipate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this blog](http://mitchellh.com/comparing-filesystem-performance-in-virtual-machines), which has some very rudimentary tests showing that shared folders have horrible  performance when writing files, and the read speed is still much slower than NFS.

[This one](http://brianreiter.org/2012/10/31/solving-very-slow-visual-studio-build-times-in-vmware/) also shows that VMware shared folders are terribly slow, but it uses an older version of VMware.

Since the benchmarks show that reads are quite fast, a non-compiled/jit'ed language may work just fine, but use source control or some other kind of synchronization tool (rsync?) for development of compiled languages.

Overall, it appears that using network shared folders (NFS, SMB/CIFS) is better when source control/sync is not an option.